# How can I extract data from each line contained in a string and put this into a collection in C#

Tags: c#

I have some a collection of data inside a tuple:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>
```

- The data in Item1 is a string that represents a topic name.
- The data in Item2  consists of a string with many line feeds. Every item in between the line feeds represents tha name of a sub topic. For example my topic could be fruit and Item2 would look like
  Apple[LF]Banana[LF]Mango[LF]Pear[LF].

My Topic and SubTopic classes looks like this:

```
public partial class Topic
{
    public Topic()
    {
        this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubTopic
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

I am using Entity Framework and so far my code to return a list of Topics looks like this:

```
public IList<Topic> createTopics(string subjectName)
{
    IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> topicData = GetContent.GetType6();
    var topics = topicData.Select((o, index) => new Topic
    {
        Name = o.Item1,
        SubTopics = ??
    }
    );
    return topics.ToList(); 
}
```

Can someone tell my how I can get the SubTopic names out of Item2 and put them into SubTopics which is into the SubTopics field which is an ICollection

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for your `SubTopics = ??`

```
SubTopics = o.Item2.Split(new [] {'\n'} )
            .Select(x => new SubTopic { Name = x })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: needs `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to convert the result to an `ICollection<SubTopic>`

Comment: @BobVale Aye, I just noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IList<Topic> createTopics(string subjectName)
{
    var topics = from o in GetContent.GetType6()
                 select new Topic
                 {
                    Name = o.Item1,
                    SubTopics = o.Item2.Split('\n')
                                       .Select(x => new SubTopic { Name = x})
                                       .ToArray();
                 };
     return topics.ToList();
}
```